# How to fix Value Error with train_test_split in Python Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I am using sklearn with a numpy array.
I have 2 arrays (x, y) and they should be:

```
test_size=0.2
train_size=0.8
```

This is my current code:

```
def predict():

    sample_data = pd.read_csv("includes\\csv.csv")

    x = np.array(sample_data["day"])
    y = np.array(sample_data["balance"])


    x = x.reshape(1, -1)



    y = y.reshape(1, -1)




    print(x)
    print(y)



    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)



    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

    clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

, and it appears in the line:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Any ideas why that appears?

Comment: Did you try: `train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8)`?

Comment: It splits along the first axis, which in your samples is size 1. Review the `sklearn` docs to understand its conventions for the shapes of the inputs - number of samples versus number of features.

Comment: yes i tried that it showed the same error

Comment: how can iprevent that from happening @hpaulj

Comment: you could try:    
`x = sample_data["day"].values

    y = sample_data["balance"].values` 
and remove the reshape command

Comment: its not changing anything at all still same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that problem. Check the library "scikit-learn". sklearn have problems with the version 0.20.0+ of scikt-learn, try to do:

Windows: `pip uninstall scikit-learn`

Linux: `sudo python36 -m pip uninstall scikit-learn`

and install:

Windows: `pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1`

Linux: `sudo python36 -m pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1`

Comment: this isn't working any more. Downgrading scikit-learn also downgrades numpy and hence you cause another problem using tensorflow. `ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import`